# how to make a selection in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to see a list of players but only from one team. I can see all players like this in my teams class:

```
List <Players> list = new ArrayList<Players>();
list=db.getAllPlayers();
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but what i need is to getAllPlayers from teams where team = '5' for example. But how do i do this? This is my getAllPlayers in the sqlitehelper class

```
public List<Players> getAllPlayers() {
        List<Players> speler = new LinkedList<Players>();

        String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SPELERS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);



        Players spelers = null;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
             spelers = new Players();
             spelers.setIdSpeler(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
             spelers.setShirt(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
             spelers.setSpeler(cursor.getString(2));

               speler.add(spelers);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        Log.d("Alle spelers in DB:", speler.toString());

    return speler;
    }
```

so is there a way to change the string query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SPELERS;

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

to something like

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SPELERS + " WHERE team=?";

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "5" };
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
```

The `WHERE` specifies a standard SQL selection. `?` is a placeholder where a literal will be bound from `selectionArgs`.

Edited to add: To set the selection args from the calling method, just add a method argument, e.g.

```
public List<Players> getPlayersForTeam(int teamNumber) {
    // ...
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { Integer.toString(teamNumber) };
```

and call it like `list = getPlayersForTeam(5);`

Comment: how can i send these selectionArgs from list=db.getAllPlayers();  ? Sorry for my ignorance